# Apache/XAMPP does not give access to subdirectory

Tags: apache, xampp

I set my document root to a git repository of three.js, and the root directory lists all subfolders, except `examples/`. It also doesn't list files and folders starting with `.` (understandable, I guess) and `README.md`. Trying to access `examples` directly gives a 503 error.

There are no `.htaccess` files anywhere. There is no `IndexIgnore` anywhere. Error.log lists this:

```
[Sat Jun 02 13:35:08.169886 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 20844:tid 1996] (OS 10061)No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  : AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Sat Jun 02 13:35:08.169886 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 20844:tid 1996] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 5s
[Sat Jun 02 13:35:08.169886 2018] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 20844:tid 1996] [client 127.0.0.1:57788] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Have you check if Apache has permission to read the files?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, the whole repository was created at the same time (`git clone`), and the permisions don't seem out of ordinary. I also realized that the examples don't perform any requests so I don't need a server to run them, unlike the docs (which run into CORS issues when served from the file system).

Answer (score 0):

In your apache conf folder, see if you have a file named `/extra/httpd-ajp.conf` with a line like this:

```
ProxyPass /examples ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/examples smax=0 ttl=60 retry=5
```

If so, comment out or delete that line.  Fixed the problem for me.